# Python: replace string in the dataframe/column if only 1 word in the row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have pretty messy data I am trying to replace rows that might contain only 1 word or string with '' or empty string.

Here is the original data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'some_text': [
        'I enjoy read Mark Twain\'s Books',
        'Library is very useful',
        '/',
        '\\',
        '/ /',
        '',
        'I enjoy read Mark Twain\'s Books',
        'an',
        'the',
        'Books are interesting'
]})
```

I tried this: ( this is dropping rows). I don't want to drop the rows just replace it.

```
count = df['some_text'].str.split().str.len()
df[~(count==1)]
```

Final output needed:

```
I enjoy read Mark Twain's Books
Library is very useful


/ /

I enjoy read Mark Twain's Books


Books are interesting
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple regex here:

```
df['new_text'] = df['some_text'].str.replace('^\S+$','');
>>> df
                         some_text                         new_text
0  I enjoy read Mark Twain's Books  I enjoy read Mark Twain's Books
1           Library is very useful           Library is very useful
2                                /                                 
3                                \                                 
4                              / /                              / /
5                                                                  
6  I enjoy read Mark Twain's Books  I enjoy read Mark Twain's Books
7                               an                                 
8                              the                                 
9            Books are interesting            Books are interesting
```

Comment: Note that this regex will not replace strings that have only one word but which also have leading or trailing whitespace, though it could be modified to do so if desired.

Answer (score 2):

With the implementation you made, instead of drop the rows, asign a new value like this:

```
count = df['some_text'].str.split().str.len()
df[count == 1] = ""
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the transformation to the column without a mask:

```
df['replaced_text'] = df['some_text'].apply(lambda x: '' if len(x.strip().split()) == 1  else x) 
print(df.to_string())
df
>>

                         some_text                    replaced_text
0  I enjoy read Mark Twain's Books  I enjoy read Mark Twain's Books
1           Library is very useful           Library is very useful
2                                /                                 
3                                \                                 
4                              / /                              / /
5                                                                  
6  I enjoy read Mark Twain's Books  I enjoy read Mark Twain's Books
7                               an                                 
8                              the                                 
9            Books are interesting            Books are interesting
```

Very similar to what you have applied, the lambda function checks each string with whitespaces stripped which have length equals 1 and replace it with `''`.